# How to set a line breakpoint when using NetBeans remote debugger?

Tags: java, debugging, netbeans

When using NetBeans debugger to debug an application remotely, is it possible to set a line breakpoint on a file?

Obviously, the source and bytecode are on the remote machine... NetBeans says it doesn't recognize the file, when I type in the name of the source file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found an answer to my question.

I checked out a local copy of the source code, and then I was able to set line breakpoints fine :-)

Also it fixed a bug with "Step Over" not working - the bug existed only without the local copy, when remote debugging.

So you can have (debug-enabled) bytecode running on a remote machine, the source code on a local machine, and do a line-by-line step-through on a local debugger through the local source.